# VR games with GVR

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to work with GoogleCardboard for VR. I want to add a button to the scene so that users can return to the menu scene without using virtual reality glasses. I tried to add a button through the canvas to my scene, but I could not touch the touch screen button on the screen. I wanted to ask if you guys have the solution for that?
Thanks

Comment: your code? snippet? UI or prefab. what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

UI in VR is always tricky. What I end up doing is creating a 3D object that serves as an UI element. When the user presses a certain button I would do a raycast and see if it hits any UI elements, and execute code accordingly